# How do you add a link to slack bot button?

Tags: links, slack, bot

I've created a slack bot, and it sends messages to a channel. I've added a button, and what I'd like to accomplish is having the button redirect the user to an external website.

Is this possible?

The documentation does not indicate you can simply add a URL to the button. Below is the actions array I'm using in the slack bot. It would be awesome if you could.

```
  "actions": [{
    "name": "Go to order",
    "text": "Go to order",
    "type": "button",
    "value": "Go!"
   }]
```

Comment: Programming related questions would be better placed on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slack-api), which also has a big Slack community

Comment: mark it as accepted, or move it off this part of stack exchange ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try [Slack's Link Buttons](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-attachments#attaching_link_buttons_to_a_message), which specifically open links in new browser tabs when clicked.

```
{
    "text": "Test Link Buttons",
    "channel": "C061EG9SL",
    "attachments": [
        {
            "fallback": "Test link button to https://slack.com/",
            "actions": [
                {
                    "type": "button",
                    "name": "file_request_123456",
                    "text": "Test",
                    "url": "https://slack.com/",
                    "style": "primary"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

[Slack Message Builder example](https://api.slack.com/docs/messages/builder?msg=%7B%22text%22%3A%22Test%20Link%20Buttons%22%2C%22channel%22%3A%22C061EG9SL%22%2C%22attachments%22%3A%5B%7B%22fallback%22%3A%22Test%20link%20button%20to%20https%3A%2F%2Fslack.com%2F%22%2C%22actions%22%3A%5B%7B%22type%22%3A%22button%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22file_request_123456%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22Test%22%2C%22url%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fslack.com%2F%22%2C%22style%22%3A%22primary%22%7D%5D%7D%5D%7D)

Comment: @zero_cool If this answer solved your question, please consider marking it as solution. Thank you.